# Arcgis Javascript API , cordinates to location

Tags: javascript, api, dictionary, gis, arcgis

For example I have 2 cordinates: `54.674705589` and `25.289369548`
and I want place this cordinates on map on button click Like in this [example](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/locator_address/)

But this example is for address, I have cordinates, it's possible with this example make what I need ?

```
function locate() {
          map.graphics.clear();
          var address = {
            "SingleLine": dom.byId("address").value
          };
          locator.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
          var options = {
            address: address,
            outFields: ["Loc_name"]
          }
          locator.addressToLocations(options);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is an example of locator.

What is locator:
 - input: address
 - output: coordinates

so you can still inspire by the example, you could just ignore the locator part of code, and create a gemometry even a graphic from your coordinate, (take care of coordinate systeme) and add it on the map